# Bash - Execute a script whether a window is opening

Tags: bash, window

I would like to kill the window "Teamviewer - Sponsored Session" each time it appears. I'm working on a public computer, with a presentation video on the screen. So if I disconnect from TV, it will hide a part of the video and it's a shame to have this little popup displayed...

So i'd like to know if it's possible to catch the event "new window opened" ? Or directly this specific window ?

I'm working on bash | and slim as WM.

---

I **can't** do like `wmctrl -c "Sponsored Session"` every 2 seconds because it's in a wine window manager...

Comment: You should check the documentation of the window manager you're using, to see if there's any way to get notifications like this from it.

Comment: I'm using SLiM, as it's abandoned I don't think I will find something relevant about it (quickly checked and found nothing). Do you have some more clues about this ?

Comment: I suspect it's unlikely that any window manager provides an interface like this for shell scripts.

Comment: `while [ 1 ]; do wmctrl -c "Sponsored Session"; sleep 2; done` is my only solution then..

Comment: Oh noes.... It doesn't work because it's in a Wine window manager....